# How to create custom decorator in nestJS to implement simple encryption of the request payload from the body of an API request endpoint?

Tags: encryption, nestjs, decorator

Api inside the controller

```
import { Controller, Get, Post, Body, Param } from '@nestjs/common';
import { EncryptionService } from './encryption.service';
import { Decrypt } from 'src/common/decrypt.decorator';

@Controller('encryption')
export class EncryptionController {
  constructor(private readonly encryptionService: EncryptionService) {}

  @Post('secure-decrypt-payload')
  secureDecryptPayload(@Body() @Decrypt() decryptedText: string): string {
    return decryptedText;
  }
}
```

Contents of the decorator

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { EncryptionService } from '../encryption/encryption.service';

export const Decrypt = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) =\> {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const encryptedText = request.body.encryptedText;
    const encryptionService = new EncryptionService(); // Use your encryption service
    const decryptedText = encryptionService.decrypt(encryptedText);
    return decryptedText;
  },
);
```

Contents of `encryption.service.ts` service class.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class EncryptionService {
  decrypt(encryptedText: string): string {
    const decryptedText = encryptedText
      .split('')
      .map(char =\> String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt(0) - 1))
      .join('');
    return decryptedText;
  }
}
```

Url of the api (called through Postman)

```
http://localhost:3000/encryption/secure-decrypt-payload/
```

Request body passed to the api:

```
{
  "encryptedText": "YourEncryptedTextHere"
}
```

Response from the api:

```
{
  "encryptedText": "YourEncryptedTextHere"
}
```

I had checked if the logic of the service was working or not by using `console.log`, which printed the correct result. But the controller does not receive the correct value from the service. It just prints the request payload without decrypting.

Comment: Have written an answer. If its works for you, can you kindly accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use both `@Body` and `@Decrypt` decorator together. In this case, your `@Decrypt` decorator is not even used, which is why you are getting the same request payload as response.

To handle this,

1. Change your controller function to:

```
@Post('secure-decrypt-payload')
secureDecryptPayload(@Decrypt() decryptedText: string): string {
  return decryptedText;
}
```

2. Since your `@Decrypt` decorator is already reading the request body, no need of any change here.

```
export const Decrypt = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) =\> {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const encryptedText = request.body.encryptedText;
    const encryptionService = new EncryptionService(); // Use your encryption service
    const decryptedText = encryptionService.decrypt(encryptedText);
    return decryptedText;
  },
);
```

---

On a side note, you can pass parameters to `@Decrypt()` as well.

```
@Post('secure-decrypt-payload')
secureDecryptPayload(@Decrypt('encryptedText') decryptedText: string): string {
  return decryptedText;
}
```

This means, you can reuse the same decorator for multiple body parameters.

Then update your `@Decrypt()` decorator to:

```
export const Decrypt = createParamDecorator(
  (data: string, ctx: ExecutionContext) =\> {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const encryptedText = request.body[data];
    const encryptionService = new EncryptionService(); // Use your encryption service
    const decryptedText = encryptionService.decrypt(encryptedText);
    return decryptedText;
  },
);
```